# JabRef creates an empty line in the .bib-file for every (new) item I create or edit

Tags: jabref

- JabRef 2.10
- Win 7 64-bit

Whenever I add a new entry or edit an old one, I see that JabRef created an empty line in the source code for the bib item (which I can see in the last tab). Does anyone have any idea how to stop this behavior?

**edit** I also posted this [on the *Discussion* page of the JabRef project over at soureforge page](https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/discussion/318825/thread/77dcc8ca/?limit=25#685c).

Comment: Do you mean between each bib item or within the bib item itself?

Comment: I mean within the item itself.

Comment: I've downloaded it now and from the look of it, it is grouping entries by their class (to be honest I liked it judging by the first look)

Comment: Well, on Windows it's quite ok. On Linux it is advisable to use [`com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel`](http://www.cheshirekow.com/wordpress/?p=761) for the look and feel command.

Comment: Damnit, this is so bothersome. What does everyone else, who uses JabRef on Windows, do then? Continuously re-edit the .bib file to delete the empty lines?

Comment: You don't need to delete anything, why do you care about it? It works with/out empty lines.

Comment: It's an itch of mine. I admit it might be a bit unnecessary to be this accurate. Yet I believe it's just... "normal" to expect that a program doesn't do this.

Comment: Any updates? Does your problem still exist with the new jabref version?